# Flutter DropdownButton returns error for onChange event

Tags: flutter, error-handling, onchange, dropdownbutton

I'm writing a project and wants to add a DropDownButton but it always return error once I add onCnange event. Dropdown always returns error. I don't know what's wrong with it.[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material( child: Column( children: [
      DropdownButton(items: [], value: dropdownValue, onChanged: (String value)  {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = value;
        });
      },)
    ], ), );
  }
```

Error message

```
The argument type 'void Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(Object?)?'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function and value might be nullable, so either remove `String` type from the callback or use the nullable type.

**Solution 1**

```dart
DropdownButton<String>(
  items: [],
  value: dropdownValue,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = value;
    });
  },
)
```

**Solution 2**

```dart
DropdownButton<String>(
  items: [],
  value: dropdownValue,
  onChanged: (String? value) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = value;
    });
  },
)
```